# Dynamically show different "tap-to-execute" actions with swipe actions (RadListView)

Tags: angular, telerik, nativescript, swipe, radlistview

The Telerik Progress UI documentation for RadListView swipe actions shows how to implement static "tap-to-execute" actions ([RadListView - Swipe Actions](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/swipe-actions)), but is there a way to dynamically change, let's say the left-side action, based on some sort of outside data or the list item that is being swiped?

For Example in the IOS mail app, if a message is marked as **Unread** and you swipe right, the left-side action shows the option to mark it as *"Read"*.  And alternatively, if a message is marked as **Read** and you swipe right, the left-side actions shows the option it as *"Unread"*.  The action is determined by the list view item itself.

Is this possible with RadListView Swipe Actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You could do that. Use the `itemSwipeProgressStarted` event in which you will have access to both the current list item that's being swiped and `swipeView`. Based on the data, you could modify components inside your swipe view, get them by id and play with visibility to show / hide items and set swipe limits based on current measurements.

Comment: Could give an example? All of my efforts have proven unsuccessful

Comment: Do you have a Playground of what exactly you tried, may be I can fix that for you.

Comment: here is a quick thing I threw together https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=e6FP8n&v=2

Comment: [Here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=e6FP8n&v=3) you go, updated your sample to show Read / Unread action based on the if condition.

Comment: This is very close if you could help me with one more thing... while it does show the different "left item" based on the message property, it only calls the tap action on the **mark-read-view** View.  And after tapping Read on the first item, it does not change to Unread the second time.  It should allow me to toggle back and forth between read and unread.  Thanks again for all your help on this

Comment: You are accessing the wrong binding context, you might have to follow the docs carefully. It should be `event.view.bindingContext` instead of `args.object.bindingContext`

Comment: I'm close. It works fully on the last item in the list, the other 3 do not seem to work the same way. Not sure if I have to clear something out or something. Please see the updated version. I added some logging as well to better show what is happening https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=e6FP8n&v=11

Comment: As I already mentioned, please read the docs carefully. You were accessing the wrong swipeView. You should always take the reference of current swipe view from event object and look for read / unread views. Also you won't need an absolute layout in this case, [update example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=e6FP8n&v=12)

Comment: I see what you did with the view.  I was miss understanding what you were talking about.  Your updated example still did not work fully, but it got me on the right track I still used the absolute layout and the visibility attribute and it is working perfectly now.  Thank you for all your help
[fully working version](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=e6FP8n&v=13)